# Make a <ul> list of items collapsible

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating an web-app using python with Flask, Bootstrap and JavaScript. I have and adjacency list accessed by the app with flask_sqlalchemy. I'm already able to extract the data from the DB and transform the adjacency list in to a list of Python dict, here's an example of the resulting list:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'External sector', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'Capital and financial markets', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 77, 'name': 'Credit indicators', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 15, 'name': 'Economic activity', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 17, 'name': 'Monetary indicators', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 30, 'name': 'Regional economy', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 114, 'name': 'International economy', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 157, 'name': 'National private financial system', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 176, 'name': 'Financial Stability', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 222, 'name': 'Financial Inclusion', 'parent_id': 0},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'Exchange rates', 'parent_id': 1},
 {'id': 242, 'name': 'Controlled or free rates', 'parent_id': 2},
 {'id': 243, 'name': 'Floating rates', 'parent_id': 2},
 {'id': 244, 'name': 'Enabled series', 'parent_id': 3},
 {'id': 4, 'name': 'Financial market indicators', 'parent_id': 3},
 {'id': 245, 'name': 'Interest rate', 'parent_id': 4},
 {'id': 5, 'name': 'Time deposits', 'parent_id': 3},
 {'id': 6, 'name': '(CDB/RDB)', 'parent_id': 5},
 {'id': 246, 'name': 'Time deposits referred in preset rates', 'parent_id': 6},
 {'id': 247,
  'name': 'Time deposits referred in postset rates',
  'parent_id': 6},
...
```

The function: this function transform the items of this list in to a list in html

```py
output = ''

#NOTE: the node variable was defined earlier and it is the list representing the adjacency list.

def build_node(node):
    global output
    output += '<li><a>'+node['name']+'</a>'
    build_nodes(node['id'])
    output += '</li>'

def build_nodes(node_parent_id):
    global output
    subnodes = [node for node in nodes if node['parent_id'] == node_parent_id]
    if len(subnodes) > 0 : 
        output += '<ul>'
        [build_node(subnode) for subnode in subnodes]
        output += '</ul>'

build_nodes(0) # Pass in None as a parent id to start with top level nodes

print(output)
```

The code output works perfectly (you can find the output in this pastebin https://pastebin.com/eSxcJ1cr).

How do I make this output collapsible using Bootstrap? I've tried putting `class="collapsable"` in the `<a></a>` tags in the function but this is not working.

NOTE: I can also extract the info from the database in to a nested dixt format, it goes like this:

```py
{'id': 0,
 'name': 'Root node',
 'parent_id': 0,
 'sub': [{'id': 1,
          'name': 'External sector',
          'parent_id': 0,
          'sub': [{'id': 2,
                   'name': 'Exchange rates',
                   'parent_id': 1,
                   'sub': [{'id': 242,
                            'name': 'Controlled or free rates',
                            'parent_id': 2,
                            'sub': []},
                           {'id': 243,
                            'name': 'Floating rates',
                            'parent_id': 2,
                            'sub': []},
                           {'id': 532,
                            'name': 'Real and effective exchange rate indices',
                            'parent_id': 2,
                            'sub': []},
                           {'id': 533,
                            'name': 'Foreign exchange and wage indicators',
                            'parent_id': 2,
                            'sub': []},
                           {'id': 548,
                            'name': 'Average of period',
                            'parent_id': 2,
                            'sub': []},
                           {'id': 549,
                            'name': 'End of period',
                            'parent_id': 2,
                            'sub': []}]},
                  {'id': 353,
```

I've tried to pass this dict to my page as a JSON string with Flask and used bootstrap-treeview to build the tree, but I had no success.

Comment: By collapsible, which elements do you want collapsed, and which elements do you want to toggle the collapse?

Comment: You can use the `<details>` tag: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/ExZaMXg?editors=1000

Comment: @Parzival, I want to make a tree menu from this list ( like this one : https://codepen.io/SaintGamer/pen/pjmzKR ). And i believe i just need to add a class to this `<a>` tag like the bootstrap `collapsable`. Basically i can toggle all the nodes except the terminal ones.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal but can i make it nested?

Comment: @Occhima Yes you can nest them... https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/poRvmBG?editors=1000

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal any idea on how i can make the items cascade when toggled?

Comment: @Occhima This might help:

Comment: 1) https://css-tricks.com/how-to-animate-the-details-element-using-waapi/

Comment: 2) https://codepen.io/Mamboleoo/pen/QWEpLqm

Comment: 3) https://codepen.io/stoumann/pen/ExydEYL

Comment: @Occhima I would suggest adding a break (br) tag into your tag before the ul and after the closing ul - you'd get a better-formatted raw output..

Comment: @RachelGallen, ty i will do that. Im trying to find some solutions using bootstrap, my guts are are telling me that i just need to add a class properly, i must admit that im not that good with html and css

Comment: @Occhima add the tags into your function. `<br>` is a break , just  add into the output lines